# What is the first recorded instance of a stage name?

Tags: history, names

To me, it seems as though stage names did not become very common until recently. Maybe I am wrong, but either way, this got me wondering what the first recorded instance of a stage name is. I am curious to see how far back in time it is and which culture it was in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What is the first recorded instance of a stage name?

First I used [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stage+name&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)

This gave the earliest use of "stage name" as around 1800.

Then I searched Google Books using ["stage name" 1800 - Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22stage+name%22+1800&lr=lang_en&newwindow=1&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1800%2Ccd_max%3A1901%2Clr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=GmR_Y7uIBZOBhbIPuoOYyAU&ved=0ahUKEwi7_bup6cb7AhWTQEEAHboBBlkQ4dUDCAg&uact=5&oq=%22stage+name%22+1800&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEANQxQVY5hFg1xNoAHAAeACAAZ4CiAG7CJIBBTAuNS4xmAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-books)

This returned [English Literature and Books Printed in England Prior to 1800 books.google.co.uk › books](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=gy3hAAAAMAAJ&q=%22stage+name%22+1800&dq=%22stage+name%22+1800&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&printsec=frontcover&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjs_Nfe6cb7AhWnTEEAHcf8DiwQ6AF6BAgFEAI)

with the following extract:

> Found inside – Page 47
> ... designed to commemorate the personality and distinguished acting career of M.-E. Joly ( 1761-1798 ) , was edited by Du Lomboy whom she married in 1781 ; **she had insisted in continuing to use her maiden name as a stage name**.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

So the earliest usage I can find is somewhere between 1761-1798 probably around 1781 by Marie Elisabeth Joly (a French Actress):

> **Marie Elisabeth Joly**
>
> Also known as
>
> Marie Elisabeth Joly
> primary name: Joly, Marie Elisabeth
> other name: Joly, Marie
>
> Details
>
> individual; actor/entertainer; French; Female
>
> Life dates
>
> 1761-1798
>
> Biography
>
> Actress; performed from an early age; debut at the Comédie-Française in 1781. Married cavalry officer Nicolas Fouquet Dulomboy.

Source: [Collections Online | British Museum](https://www.britishmuseum.org/collection/term/BIOG228767)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, whether actors are also asked for, given that this is *Music Fans*; if so
[Turlupin (French Wikipedia)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turlupin_(acteur)) was a stage name of Henri Legrand, 1587-1637, so stage names seem not exactly to be a new appearance.